# Dropdown items getting populated when I am repeating the form array in angular 5

Tags: html, typescript, angular5, angular-ngmodel

I am working on form array in which drop-down items have to load based on previous drop-down values but when I am adding a new same form dropdown values getting loaded based on the last dropdown values. Is there someone help me with this.

Answer (score 1):

Using patch value and form control we can achieve this.